# Clang error when compiling Assembly file for iOS archive

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly, compiler-errors, clang

I get the following error when trying to compile **.s** file while **archiving** the app with **Xcode 9.4.1/ LLMV 9.0**.

`Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1`

```
error: invalid operand for instruction
add x1, x1, x14
```

When I run the project on a physical device, there are no compile errors, everything works as expected.

**Solved:**
Leave only ARM64 in Active Architectures section in Build Settings.

Comment: Are you sure you were compiling for AArch64, and not x86-64 or something?  x86-64 and AArch64 both have an `add` instruction, but those are AArch64 register names, so the error message makes sense for x86-64.  (Or for ARM32...)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Removing ARMv7 and ARMv7s from Valid Architectures and leaving only ARM64 solved the issue. Thank you.